# Why does "admin' #" work as a sql injection attack on MySql but "admin' --" doesn't?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-injection

Isn't `--` a valid MySql comment also?

Comment: Yes, `--` starts a line comment. In MySQL it has to be followed by a space, but that's nonstandard.

Comment: It's worth saying that neither of them will work if you're doing it right.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try `admin' -- .` with a space and something to make your browser keep the space.

See also the [manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/comments.html).

Comment: Ah, just saw the comment above.  Thanks.

Comment: Because "--" is not a comment but "-- " is. Some Browser like to remove the space at the end, so "-- ." is safer.